# Unexpected results in minimum bottles Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memoization

The following Java code calculates the minimum number of bottles required to store a given volume of liquid. Bottles storage capacities are {1,5,7,10}. It works fine for small values (like 4 digit numbers) but breaks for larger values like 99999 (stack overflow error), 1000000 (incorrect answer) and above. What is the problem with the code? Corrected code along with glitch description is expected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Minimise
{
  static final int INF = 1000000000;
  static int dp[]=new int[1000010];

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter the volume");
    int size = s.nextInt();

    Arrays.fill(dp, 0, 100000, -1);

    System.out.println("minimum number of bottles needed:\n"+findmin(size));
   }

  static int findmin(int size)
   {
    if(size<0)
        return INF;
    else if(size==0)
        return 0;        

    if( dp[size] != -1 )
        return dp[size];        
    else
    {
        dp[size] = min( findmin(size-10)+1, findmin(size-7)+1, findmin(size-5)+1, findmin(size-1)+1 );            
        return dp[size];
    }
 }

  static int min(int a,int b,int c,int d)
  {
    int arr[] = new int[4];
    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = b;
    arr[2] = c;
    arr[3] = d;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr[0];
   }
  }
```

Comment: Change recursion to iteration.

Comment: Maybe you want findmin(size-1)+1 for the first term instead of findmin(size-10)+1... (the latter appears twice and you can't get some volumes without /subtracting/ bottles without the 1-sized.

Comment: @BadZen my bad. corrected with no change in results.

Comment: Arrays.fill(dp, 0, 100000, -1)  leaves dp[100000] >= 0

Comment: As for the stack overflow error, increase your jvm stack size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Arrays.fill(dp, 0, dp.length, -1)
```

You were leaving dp[100000] >= 0.

For stack overflow error, Use Moar Stack:

```
java -Xss4m Minimise
```